# AngularJS angular-ui bootstrap timepicker as dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i like to show the timepicker as a dropdown (popup) in a input element like the datepicker.
Is there any easy way to accomplish this or is a complete new directive necessary ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container container-fluid" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       var1={{var1}}
      <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
      <div class="well">
        <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
          <input data-format="hh:mm:ss"  type="text" id="input1" name="input1"></input>
          <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>

  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.var1 = '12-07-2013';
});


app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({           
           language: 'en',
           pickDate: false,          
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/905/)</kbd>

Comment: yeah but i looking for the timepicker as popup

Comment: and what is that? its dropdown, see image posted

Comment: Opps, you can create directive and use bootstrap timepicker, see my 2nd edit